# Get list of gaming live streams on Youtube

Tags: api, youtube, stream, live

I'm trying to use the Youtube Data API to grab the list of currently gaming related live streams but I can't find any endpoint that fit what I need and return the number of viewers for each of those channels.

Do you guys have any idea of how I could manage to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of gaming live streams:**
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&**videoCategoryId=20**&regionCode=US&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY_HERE}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&videoCategoryId=20&regionCode=US&maxResults=50&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE)

videoCategoryId=20 is "Gaming"

**Getting the live stream details (like viewer numbers):**
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CliveStreamingDetails&**id={VIDEO_ID_HERE}**&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(title%2CliveBroadcastContent)%2CliveStreamingDetails%2FconcurrentViewers)&key={YOUR_API_KEY_HERE}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CliveStreamingDetails&id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(title%2CliveBroadcastContent)%2CliveStreamingDetails%2FconcurrentViewers)&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE)

Substitue the parts of these links that are in `{}` with your appropriate values.

Comment: These urls doesn't look very well in this post, I suggest to make them somehow better.

Comment: Damn, sorry I forgot to validate the answer. That would have been much better to have the whole data with one query but that do the job, thanks :)