# Is it possible to get a list of users in a Youtube Gaming Live Stream

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am working with the Youtube Live Streaming api. I don't see this, but I am wondering if there is a way to get a list of all viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the specific stream's `videoId` you can use the undocumented live_stats endpoint to get the number of viewers:

```
https://www.youtube.com/live_stats?v={videoid}
```

Comment: Looks good. Does this only work while a stream is live? I am unable to test on a video from the Live Broadcasts endpoint on a video that was live.

Comment: @KeithHolliday I believe the video has to be live currently.  I just recently learned about this undocumented endpoint, it must be used internally by YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

@JAL - your answer works great. Thanks, I have also found success using this url:

**Getting the live stream details (like viewer numbers)**:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CliveStreamingDetails&id={VIDEO_ID_HERE}&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(title%2CliveBroadcastContent)%2CliveStreamingDetails%2FconcurrentViewers)&key={YOUR_API_KEY_HERE}
```

I found this url from another question: [Get list of gaming live streams on Youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616252/get-list-of-gaming-live-streams-on-youtube).