# Is it possible to get a list of users in a Youtube Live Stream

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am using youtube data api.

But I have not found anywhere to fetch the list of users who participated in youtube liveStream.

I know how to get the number of viewers : 
[Is it possible to get a list of users in a Youtube Gaming Live Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715244/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-users-in-a-youtube-gaming-live-stream)

I want to get a list of participating users, not Number of participants.

Is there a way?